# Accordian Item to be placed on top of window

Tags: jquery, html, css, accordion

I have a requirement where i should have to `display` my active `accordian` to be on top of the window

Currently i'm using the following `jQuery` code.

```
$('span').click(function () {
        $('.hide').slideUp();
        $(this).parent().find('.hide').slideDown();
        var myScroll = $(this).offset().top;
        $(window).scrollTop(myScroll);
    })
```

Please see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wizam/w5m57/1/) where you can find rest of my code.

if i click the `span` having text clickable, i want this clickable and the expanded text to be on the top of the `window` and similarly the other clickables should do.

P.S I want a `jQuery` solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But why a -1???? whomever... comment here.. at least i will know my mistake... or if it is that simple please answer...

Comment: Is this the type of general functionality you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/w5m57/2/. I'm just looking for generally what you want, not the details.

Comment: no @TimSPQR if i click on clickable, i just want to scroll the window so that i shud be able to see clickable on the top... followed by the content... and then the other clickables with content hidden. thanks that you have responded.... :) the top most content which says not clickable shud be present but shud appear just if i scroll up

Comment: Is this closer to what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/w5m57/3/

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a leap of faith and guess that this is close to what you want.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/w5m57/4/)

JS

```
$('span').click(function(){
      $( '.hide' ).hide();
      var spanclass = $(this).attr('class');
      $( '#' + spanclass ).toggle( 1000 );
            });
```